# Finding Probability density function of a random variable with transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let random variable X have the probability density function

f(x)= $\frac{x}{2}$ for $0<x<2$

0 otherwise

Find the pdf of $Y=X^3$

Now I’m quite new to this, I’m trying to find $P(Y<y)$ and then finding the CDF from it integrating which I can just differentiate to get the pdf of Y but I’m not sure about the change of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$P(Y\leq y)=P(X^3\leq y)=P(X\leq y^{1/3})$$

Comment: is this right:  $g^{-1}(Y)=y^{1/3}$

$\frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy} = \frac{1}{3}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}$

$F_{y}Y = \frac{y^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{6}$

Comment: If you want to use the Jacobian method:$f_Y(y)=|J|f_X(y^{1/3})$ where $J=\frac{1}{3} y^{-2/3}$